# How do you deal with errors in parition?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, multidplyr

I am attempting to partition my data-set such that all members of a group are sent to the same core, I am following online tutorials verbatim but there seems to be an issue. The Error is : 
Error in partition(., group, cluster = clust) : unused argument (group)

```
data<-sqlQuery(conn,Query) ##import data according to query 
cl<-as.numeric(detectCores())##find the number of cores 

clust<-new_cluster(detectCores()) 
clust<-default_cluster()
data <- data %>% group_by(rowno_dmddmhi_dmd) %>% mutate(group = sample(1:cl,1))

####clustering

by_group<-data%>%partition(group, cluster = clust)
```

because I have 16 cores each group was assigned a number 1:16 this is held in the group column